# POST запрос с получением ответа

Tags: c#, post, webclient, tcpclient

Нужно отправить POST запрос и получить ответ от сервера, сделал след образом:

```
var bytePost = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);

var client = new TcpClient {ReceiveTimeout = context.MaxSearchTimeOut.Seconds};

client.Connect(BaseAddress, 80);

var stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(bytePost, 0, bytePost.Length);

var responseData = new byte[4096];
var strWesponse = string.Empty;
var bytes = stream.Read(responseData, 0, responseData.Length);
strWesponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseData, 0, bytes);
stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

И столкнулся с проблемой, что бы это работало адрес должен быть следующего вида: `BaseAddress = "blog.site.ru"`, а у меня он след вида: `BaseAddress = "blog.site.ru/online/page.php"`.

Поиск решения проблемы подсказал что необходимо использовать WebClient вместо TcpClient.

Пытался сделать следующим образом, но `webResponse` всегда пуст.

```
var bytePost = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);

using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var webResponse = webClient.UploadData(BaseAddress, "POST", bytePost);

    var strWebResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(webResponse);
}
```

Что я делаю не так и как мне исправить данную проблему?

**UPD.**

Пытаюсь сделать через HttpClient, но ответ всегда пуст.

```
var bytePost = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient {Timeout = context.MaxSearchTimeOut})
{
    var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(BaseAddress, new ByteArrayContent(bytePost));

    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var httpByteContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
```

Comment: [HttpClient Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @tym32167 сейчас посмотрю что это такое)

Comment: [HttpClient makes GET and POST very simple](https://blog.jayway.com/2012/03/13/httpclient-makes-get-and-post-very-simple/)

Comment: Только `using` не забудьте `using (var client = new HttpClient()) {....}`

Comment: @tym32167 Я правильно понимаю что `var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(BaseAddress, new ByteArrayContent(bytePost));` отправляет мои данные на сервер, а `var httpByteContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();` получает ответ? Просто ответ пустой приходит, а в TcpClient что я делал, приходил ответ.

Comment: Установите себе fiddler и/или postman и глядите, что вы реально отпрвляете и какой ответ приходит.